# How to make 'submit' button disabled?

Tags: forms, angular

How to disable the "Submit" button until the form is valid?

Does angular2 have an equivalent to ng-disabled that can be used on the Submit button? (ng-disabled doesn't work for me.)

Comment: only when you use inmediate validation, for example on typing. Don't do this.. only with good thought or with asynchronous validation, that relies on a backend for example.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

As seen in this Angular [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/57496926cad0d840092c7623079883983ca07d53/modules/examples/src/model_driven_forms/index.ts), there is a way to disable a button until the whole form is valid:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!ngForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

Comment: how to get value of radio and checkbox using formBuilder ?

Comment: referred link has old syntax's for angular2 for example `ng-form-modal`. ask him to update thanx.

Comment: Check this example, the syntax is up to date -> http://blog.jhades.org/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Comment: how can you validate a form if you disable the submit button (unless you do it on the flow but I don't always like that)? Please be aware of UX concerns here ..

Comment: [disabled]="ngForm.invalid" you can also check

Comment: Why not use [disabled]="ngForm.status". It is more powerful and dynamic then just using invalid argument. Bcz for "ngForm.invalid" to work, you will also need to place flags if all the input-groups are not empty. If you use can use FormBuilder it will be much more flexible.

Answer (score 60):

in **Angular 2.x.x** , **4**, **5** ...

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" required> 
    <button  type="submit"  [disabled]="loginForm.form.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 17):

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="contactForm">

<button [disabled]="contactForm.invalid"  (click)="onSubmit()">SEND</button>
```

.ts

```
contactForm: FormGroup;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a working example (you'll have to trust me that there's a submit() method on the controller - it prints an Object, like {user: 'abc'} if 'abc' is entered in the input field):

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(loginForm.value)">
    <input type="text" name="user" ngModel required>
    <button  type="submit"  [disabled]="loginForm.invalid">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

As you can see:

- don't use loginForm.form, just use loginForm

  loginForm.invalid works as well as !loginForm.valid

  if you want submit() to be passed the correct value(s), the input element should have name and ngModel attributes

Also, this is when you're NOT using the new FormBuilder, which I recommend. Things are very different when using FormBuilder.

Answer (score 4):

Form validation is very much straight forward in Angular 2

Here is an example,

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" 
   required [(ngModel)]="firstname" name="firstname">
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="middlename">Middle Name</label>
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="middlename" 
   [(ngModel)]="middlename" name="middlename">
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="lastname" 
   required minlength = '2' maxlength="6" [(ngModel)] = "lastname" name="lastname">
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="mobnumber">Mob Number</label>
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="mobnumber"  
   minlength = '2' maxlength="10" pattern="^[0-9()\-+\s]+$" 
   [(ngModel)] = "mobnumber" name="mobnumber">
 </div>

 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

[Check this plunker for demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JA9MeTRTu8oylvhVUq69)

[More info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/10/disable-submit-button-until-all.html)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

### .ts

```
newForm : FormGroup;
```

### .html

```
<input type="button" [disabled]="newForm.invalid" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important that you include the "**required**" keyword inside each one of your mandatory input tags for it to work.

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)" #loginForm="ngForm">
    ...
    <input ngModel required name="username" id="userName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name..." />
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be below code can help:

```
<button type="submit" [attr.disabled]="!ngForm.valid ? true : null">Submit</button>
```