# Angular2 custom button

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a custom button component and I am using it in one of templates. I want to disable this button component using disabled property when the form is invalid. How do I achieve this? which Angular API I can use?
For instance:
In html i am using "app-okbutton" component "I want to use disable property like this [disabled]="??" in app-okbutton
Image for reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3xdR.png

Link to my repo for reference
https://github.com/hemantmali21/Angular2-Demo/blob/master/src/app/okbutton/okbutton.component.ts

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Forms - Submit Button Disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062051/angular2-forms-submit-button-disabled)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo In my case I am creating submit button as custom component and when I use that component in other html I want to pass input property disabled.Please help me figure out where I am getting wrong Here is my repo https://github.com/hemantmali21/Angular2-Demo/tree/master/src/app

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks man!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-okbutton',
  template: `
  <button [disabled]="disabled"
    [type]= "type" class="btn btn-primary {{className}}" (click)="onClickEvent.emit($event)">
          Save
  </button>
  `,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class OkbuttonComponent {
  @Input() className = ''; // default value if none is passed
  @Input() type = 'button'; // default value if none is passed
  @Input() disabled = false; // default value if none is passed
  @Output() onClickEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

And then you can use it as follows (with a form for example):

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate>
// form fields go here
</form>
<app-okbutton [disabled]="!form.valid"></app-okbutton>
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to use the native (click) event on the component. But if you do `<app-okbutton (click)="foo()">` it seems the component can't stop the click event from firing if it's disabled. Is there a way?