# How to disable button in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have an `Angular7 app` & using `Reactive Forms Module` for validation & forms.

this is how my template looks like.

```
<div class="row" [formGroup]="jobForm">
<div class="form-group"
 [ngClass]="{'has-error': jobForm.get('jobTitle').errors && 
  (jobForm.get('jobTitle').touched || jobForm.get('jobTitle').dirty)  }">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="jobTitle" />
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="formError">
  {{ formError.jobTitle }}
</span>
</div>
 <br />
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="jobTitle.errors.required"
(click)="submit(jobTitle,jobDesc)">Create</button>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-create-job',
templateUrl: './create-job.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./create-job.component.css']
})
export class CreateJobComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
 jobForm: FormGroup;
 formError: any;
 validationMessages = {
  jobTitle: { required: 'Job Title required'},
  jobCode: { required: 'Job Coderequired'},
  };

 ngOnInit() {
  this.jobForm = this.fb.group({
  jobTitle: ['', Validators.required]
});
this.formError = {
  jobTitle: '', jobCode : ''
};
this.jobForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  this.logValidationError(this.jobForm);
});
```

}

There are such 2-3 input elements which has validation.

How can I disable the submit if any of the validation has error. I don't want to go one by one property as I did for one property.

I mean if `formError` has any error, keep the button disable & initially disable.

Thanks!

Comment: try  `[disabled]="!jobForm.valid"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Forms - Submit Button Disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062051/angular2-forms-submit-button-disabled)

Answer (score 22):

You need to check whether the form is `valid`.

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!jobForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

[Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use ternary operator as disabled accepts **true** and **null** to work properly

## So you can try

```
<button 
   type="button" 
   class="btn btn-primary" 
   [disabled]="jobTitle.errors.required? true: null"
   (click)="submit(jobTitle,jobDesc)">
      Create
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="jobForm.form.invalid"
(click)="submit(jobTitle,jobDesc)">Create</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must to check is the form is valid or not.

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
  <input required name="uri" [(ngModel)]="data">
  <button [disabled]="!f.valid">Submut</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Avoid posting code-only answers, [edit] your answer and add some explanation how your code solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

> Just make the button rely on the validity of the form.

This will take care of errors as well as pristine (initial) condition.

Example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!jobForm.valid"
(click)="submit(jobTitle,jobDesc)">Create</button>
```