# Enable or disable button based on a value

Tags: angular

I have a list of buttons like this

```
<div style="position: absolute; top:0; right: 0;">
 <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']"> Dashboard </button>
 <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/admin/templates-dashboard']"  > Templates </button>
 <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/admin/roles-dashboard']" > Users </button>
 <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/corporate/dashboard']"> Corporates </button>
 <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/archive']"> Archive </button>
 <button id="name-btn" class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/my-profile']"  >
        <span id="circle"></span> {{ name }}
 </button>
 <button  id="logout-btn" (click)="isDialogOpen = true" class="main">Log out</button>
</div>
```

I then have a user role that is stored in local storage. I am now trying to disable/enable the above buttons based on the users role.

eg if the userRole is a system admin then disable the Archive button but if the userRole is HR Admin then enable the Archive button

I am trying the following but it does not seem to be working as expected

```
isDisabled(userRole: string): boolean {
    if (userRole == 'System Admin') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }
```

[`disabled]="isDisabled(userRole)"`

Comment: Where is `userRole` from?

Comment: userRole is stored in localStorage

Comment: Which button are you trying to disable?

Comment: All the buttons will be enabled/disabled based on the user role. For now I am trying to disable the archive button if the user is System Admin but it must be enabled if it is a HR Admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Forms - Submit Button Disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062051/angular2-forms-submit-button-disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still make use of the input bindings and bind the `disabled` attribute of all buttons to the `isDisabled()` method. You won't be able to access `userRole` on your template (component.html) unless you have set it as a property.

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled()" class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/archive']"> Archive </button>
```

And on your component.ts, you can get the `userRole` within the `isDisabled()` method. I am assuming the key is called `userRole` as well.

```
isDisabled(): boolean {
    var userRole = storage.getItem(`userRole`);
    if (userRole == 'System Admin') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do I then need to make one function per button to specify which user role has access to which button?

Comment: @skydev yes, you need to include` [disabled]="isDisabled()"` on all buttons that require that perticular function